# What are the main ways to do a reverse iteration in Nim?

Tags: iterator, iteration, nim-lang

I'm learning Python. I recently learned about Nim and began to study it too. I liked the python+pascal syntax and the speed of C. Unfortunately, there is much less educational information and reference books about Nim than there is about Python. I don't quite understand how to properly perform a reverse iteration in Nim.

In Python, it's easy. For example, for a "for" loop, the var[::-1] method works easily. And it seems that in Nim it just doesn't work that way. Something like var[^1..0] just give me an error. I was able to do reverse iteration using len() and the "ind" variable that simply gets smaller with each loop.

Here is a code example.

```
const str: string = "Hello world!"
var str_2: string
var ind: int = len(str)

for i in str:
  ind.inc(-1)
  str_2.add(str[ind])

echo str_2
```

It's work. But this is not a pythonic solution. An unnecessary bicycle. In a good way, there should be built-in tools for reverse iteration. Nim experts, what are the main methods of reverse iteration?

Sorry for my English. I write with the help of an online translator.

I tried using a reverse iteration like var[^1..0]. It just gives an error. I also tried to use the "countdown" function, but that's not what it's needed for. I would like to learn about the main and right methods of reverse iteration in Nim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also tried to use the "countdown" function, but that's not what it's needed for.

I don't know what's wrong with [`countdown`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#countdown.i%2CT%2CT%2CPositive). For example, you can use it to iterate from `a.len - 1` down to `0` (much like Pascal's `for r := length(a) - 1 downto 0 do`), and `add` the characters at those positions, thus in reverse order, to a new string:

```
const a: string = "Hello world!"

var b: string
for r in countdown(a.len - 1, 0): b.add a[r]
echo b
```

But to just reverse a string, you could also go using an openArray and [`reversed`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/algorithm.html#reversed%2CopenArray%5BT%5D) from `std/algorithm`, then `cast` it back to a string:

```
import std/algorithm

const a: string = "Hello world!"
echo cast[string](a.reversed)
```

Or, as @xbello has pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143746?noredirect=1#comment137779781_78143819), use the [same procedure](https://nim-lang.org/docs/unicode.html#reversed%2Cstring) from `std/unicode`, which directly (accepts and) returns string types, eliminating the need to `cast` manually.

```
import std/unicode

const a: string = "Hello world!"
echo a.reversed
```

All of the above produce:

```
!dlrow olleH
```

Comment: Oooh, so this can be done using countown(). So I got confused somewhere in the past. It's much clearer now. Thank you very much for the excellent advice. Now I will definitely use these methods. 

Comment: Also in `std/unicode` you have the procedure `proc reversed(s: string): string`. It's only syntactic sugar over the @pmf second solution.